# How can I trigger a variation change on dynamically loaded products in a WooCommerce product loop?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How do I trigger variation change on dynamically loaded products in loop?

I have added the variation select form to my variable products in the products loop and it works when it's loaded with the page but I'm also loading products with AJAX and the variation change doesn't trigger on these products.

What do I need to call to get it to fire?

I've tested this with products loaded with the page and it works as expected just not triggering on the dynamically loaded products

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize `wc_variation_form()` function on the variation form after loading the products through ajax, something like

```
success: () => {
  ....
  // Loop over newly loaded products.
         loadedProduct.find('.variations_form' ).wc_variation_form();
}
```